# How to control the screen slide by code in the android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to writing an app that can help me to control my screen.
For example,I can press a button,and my android phone can help me to slide from left to right by itself.

Please refer to the picture as below.

[image]

I saw some of the Transfer beads Game Cheat MAYBE use this method to control the screen slide automatically, but actually I don't know how it does.

For another example, refer form the following video. In this video,he made the phone slide the screen by itself. What I want to do is as same as his work. =)

https://youtu.be/a5quGThvjT4

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: what did you try and what is your code by now working with this issue?

Comment: I tried to find the answer from the website, but I think I need some key words. I spent lots of time but I didn't find any useful thing.

Comment: So.... I haven't started my work yet, I need more information that can help me to know how to start this work.

Comment: Ok, do you need to slide between some screens, perhaps "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" can help you on this. You define your fragments and can simple switch to one as you need programatically. If you need some example i post a whole answer on this topic with a little example

Comment: Thank you! But I don't need to slide between screen. For another example,  you can refer form this video [link](https://youtu.be/a5quGThvjT4) . In this video,he made the phone slide the screen by itself. What I want to do is as same as his work. =)

Comment: Ok, so the video shows something what you didn't explain well in your question. You have one screen/activity and you want to simulate a gesture programmatically on some events, e.g. when you shake the phon to drag from a specific point to another, is that right?

Comment: Yes! That's what I want! And also Sorry that I don't know how to explain this function exactly. =( I don't know the keyword of this function. I think this cause I can't find the answer from the website.

Comment: Ok, perhaps the keyword will be better drag and drop and not swipe, since swipe is changing between views. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html. I didn't really check on it, if it's the right thing for you but perhaps it helps. If it help, let me know and i give a real answer you can accept on this. Dont hesitate to ask more if things stay unclear. And don't feel sorry about that you dont know the right buzzwords by now, everyone starts at a point.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! That really help. I will study this and try to start my work these days. =)

Comment: u are welcome, let me know if things go in the right direction

Comment: I am not sure that this can help me to finish my work. I need some times to try and make sure this is the right answer.  But these keywords really help me. I can accept on this. =)

Comment: lets see the next days to work on this, i will make the answer now and but you can accept when your problem is solved. As i said, dont hesitate to get in touch if you dont get your problem solved by yourself

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I will try my best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it figured out the OP needs a drag/drop on the same screen for his problem and not swiping between activities or fragments:

The keyword is "android drag and drop": https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html